# How to reference tagged attributes in conditions

Tags: freeradius

I'm running into an issue i just can't figure out. Within FreeRadius i use the "post-proxy" section to evaluate conditions. This has always worked fine for me. However, now i'm facing a strange issue:

This is the Access-Accept i receive:

```
(11877) Tue Jul  2 10:21:36 2019: Debug:   Received Access-Accept Id 198 from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:1812 to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:53259 length 309
(11877) Tue Jul  2 10:21:36 2019: Debug:   Proxy-State = 0x3731
(11877) Tue Jul  2 10:21:36 2019: Debug:   Framed-Protocol = PPP
(11877) Tue Jul  2 10:21:36 2019: Debug:   Service-Type = Framed-User
(11877) Tue Jul  2 10:21:36 2019: Debug:   Tunnel-Medium-Type:0 = IEEE-802
(11877) Tue Jul  2 10:21:36 2019: Debug:   Tunnel-Private-Group-Id:0 = "530"
(11877) Tue Jul  2 10:21:36 2019: Debug:   Tunnel-Type:0 = VLAN
(11877) Tue Jul  2 10:21:36 2019: Debug:   EAP-Message = 0x030c0004
(11877) Tue Jul  2 10:21:36 2019: Debug:   Class = 0xXXXXX
(11877) Tue Jul  2 10:21:36 2019: Debug:   MS-CHAP-Domain = "XXXXX"
(11877) Tue Jul  2 10:21:36 2019: Debug:   MS-CHAP2-Success = 0xXXXXX
(11877) Tue Jul  2 10:21:36 2019: Debug:   MS-MPPE-Send-Key = 0xXXXXX
(11877) Tue Jul  2 10:21:36 2019: Debug:   MS-MPPE-Recv-Key = 0xXXXXX
(11877) Tue Jul  2 10:21:36 2019: Debug:   Message-Authenticator = 0xXXXXX
```

When i try to evaluate the VLAN / Tunnel-Private-Group-Id i get this:

```
(11877) Tue Jul  2 10:21:36 2019: Debug:       if (proxy-reply:Tunnel-Private-Group-ID == "530") {
(11877) Tue Jul  2 10:21:36 2019: ERROR:       Failed retrieving values required to evaluate condition
```

Am i missing something obvious? And can someone tell me what the ":0" means behind these three attributes:

> Tunnel-Medium-Type:0
>
> Tunnel-Private-Group-Id:0
>
> Tunnel-Type:0

I've looked al over the internet but couldn't find documentation about it. My guess is it has something to do with the inner/outer tunnel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course it had to be something obvious, and it was.

It seems that a attribute filter was applied that filtered the Tunnel-Private-Group-ID attribute during the post-proxy.

Answer (score 0):

The :0 is the tag indicator for the attribute, it means the attribute is in tag group 0.  Certain attributes have a 1 byte tag prefix which is used to group attributes that describe the same 'thing' together.

You can see tags as operating very much like a grouping TLV would, but the tagged attributes are not actually encoded within a single grouping attribute.

A common use-case of tags is to group attributes which describe a single VPN endpoint together where multiple L2TP endpoints are being specified (mostly ISP land).  Another use-case is to do something similar for attributes describing dynamic VLAN tagging (as is shown in your example packet).

The original RFC that describes tagging is [RFC2868](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2868) if you're interested in the on the wire format.

In FreeRADIUS when you're operating with tagged attributes you generally need to explicitly specify the tag value, which is why your condition above isn't working.

Try:

```
if (proxy-reply:Tunnel-Private-Group-ID:0 == "530") {
```

Or if this is FreeRADIUS 3, you should might be able to use the 'all instances' array subscript, can't remember the exact logic I implemented for matching when I wrote that code...

```
if (proxy-reply:Tunnel-Private-Group-ID[*] == "530") {
```

If you look in the dictionaries, you'll also see the tagged attributes marked up with a 'has_tag' flag as in the [dictionary file](https://github.com/FreeRADIUS/freeradius-server/blob/master/share/dictionary/radius/dictionary.rfc2868) for [RFC2868](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2868) attributes.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification on tags. I forgot to mention my colleague tried the approach you suggested:

`code`Debug: if (proxy-reply:Tunnel-Private-Group-ID:0 == "530") { ERROR:       Failed retrieving values required to evaluate condition...
`code`